# Merging two pandas data frames with duplicate ON entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with two `pandas` DataFrame (two separate years), that contains information about individuals. I'm using `pd.merge` with inner join. I can set the 'on' based on the individual names. However, I noticed that there are duplicate entries with the same name (essentially two people with the same name). To separate these records I use other fields, such as their locations. My code looks like:

```
df_combine = pd.merge(df_current, df_old, on=['Name', 'Department', 'College Name'])
```

While that works to fix this specific case, there are cases where someone with a unique name moves department. As such, this is not caught.

Is there way to first merge by name for unique cases and then for duplicate records by name to consider other fields?

For clarity, consider the records having two "Doe,John" in two different departments and one "Doe,Jane" in one department for one year and another for the second year. I would like the code to recognize the two "Doe,John" and one "Doe,Jane"

Edit, example dataframes:

Latest dataframe:

```
Name, Department, Field1
"Doe,John","ABC",555
"Doe,John","DEF",145
"Doe,Jane","FGH",205
```

Previous dataframe:

```
Name, Department, Field1
"Doe,John","ABC",345
"Doe,John","DEF",140
"Doe,Jane","ABC",200
```

Note the change in Jane Doe's department.

Expected result:

```
Name, Department, Field1_A, Field1_B
"Doe,John","ABC",555,345
"Doe,John","DEF",145,140
"Doe,Jane","FGH",205,200
```

Comment: Helpful if you can provide a copyable input dataframe and an output dataframe to check against

Comment: I edited the OP to give an example. There are other columns in this table that I'm merging together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` with `how` param seted as `'left'`, it's important the first dataframe is the latest in order to conserve the data newest. Note also, I haven't used `Field1` as key in `on` param because I want to conserve both columns in both dataframes.

```
#Sample data
df_lastest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Department', 'Field1'], data=[["Doe,John","ABC",555], ["Doe,John","DEF",145], ["Doe,Jane","FGH",205]])  
df_previous = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Department', 'Field1'], data=[["Doe,John","ABC",345], ["Doe,John","DEF",140], ["Doe,Jane","ABC",200]])

df_merge = pd.merge(df_lastest, df_previous, how='left', on=['Name', 'Department'], suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
df_merge['Field1_B'].fillna(df_previous['Field1'], inplace=True)

print(df_merge)
```

Output:

```
     Name   Department  Field1_A    Field1_B
0   Doe,John    ABC     555           345
1   Doe,John    DEF     145           140
2   Doe,Jane    FGH     205           200
```

[Screenshot using Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbkkQ.png)

Comment: This does not work entirely with the Jane Doe case as the department changes, from ABC to FGH. See the above post.

Comment: @astrochun Please testing again, I have updated the answer.

Comment: No it does not work for Jane Doe. Once again, the Department changes. Your above code assumes it's the same.

Comment: And I can't change your response to clarify, but it's "ABC" to "FGH" for Department

Comment: It's strange, I had updated that part too, I will review this answer again tomorrow. I'm almost sure I have the answer but I don't update it correctly.

Comment: @astrochun I had forgotten to update the sample data in my answer. I have added a screenshot from my Google Colab where I programmed the answer too.

Comment: Thanks, I can try it again but I wonder if my examples isn't addressing my issue directly.

Comment: Let me know if working. Would be great if you mark this answer as correct if working for you.

Comment: I think I know what my problem is. While the minimal reproducible example is a good start, these two dataframes are not identical in number of entries. As such, the inplace=True won't entirely work as we are assuming that the entries are 1:1 when we do the replacement.

Comment: @astrochun I get you, just remember you can post another question in SO too, good luck with your tasks!